# How to get wave height of a gerstner wave made in shader graph?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-shader-graph

I have followed a gerstner wave shader graph tutorial. ([YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awd1hRpLSoI&t=249s&ab_channel=Zicore))

I am now trying to implement buoyancy by attaching the following script to a gameobject. ([YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL_zHQEju8s&ab_channel=TomWeiland))

```html
using UnityEngine;

public class Floater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rigidBody;
    public float depthBeforeSubmerged = 1f;
    public float displacementAmount = 3f;
    public int floaterCount = 1;
    public float waterDrag = 0.99f;
    public float waterAngularDrag = 0.5f;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(Physics.gravity / floaterCount, transform.position, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        float waveHeight = WaveManager.instance.GetWaveHeight();

        if (transform.position.y < waveHeight)
        {
            float displacementMultiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((waveHeight - transform.position.y) / depthBeforeSubmerged) * displacementAmount;
            rigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(0f, Mathf.Abs(Physics.gravity.y) * displacementMultiplier, 0f), transform.position,                         ForceMode.Acceleration);
            rigidBody.AddForce(displacementMultiplier * -rigidBody.velocity * waterDrag * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            rigidBody.AddTorque(displacementMultiplier * -rigidBody.angularVelocity * waterAngularDrag * Time.fixedDeltaTime,           ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code you use `float waveHeight = WaveManager.instance.GetWaveHeight();` to obtain the wave height from the relevant function in the WaveManager script below, which is attached to the gerstner wave gameobject (just a subdivided plane with the shader graph material applied).

```html
public class WaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static WaveManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != this)
        {
            Debug.Log("Instance already exists, destroying object!");
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    public float GetWaveHeight()
    {
       // The formula will go here.
    }
}
```

**You are meant to use the same formula in the GetWaveHeight() function as in the shader graph.**

The problem is I don't know how to achieve this.

The following screenshots illustrate the gerstner wave shader graph setup that I have currently.

To clarify, there are 4 separate gerstner waves layered on top of each other to make it more realistic, so that will need to be incorporated into the formula.

**Frequency Subgraph**
[image: Frequency Subgraph]

**Theta Subgraph**
[image: Theta Subgraph]

**Displacement Subgraph**
[image: Displacement Subgraph]

**GerstnerWave Subgraph**
[image: GerstnerWave Subgraph]

**Gerstner Shader Graph (in 3 sections; top, middle and bottom as it was so large)**
**Top**
[image: Gerstner Shader Graph (Top)]

**Middle**
[image: Gerstner Shader Graph (Middle)]

**Bottom**
Bottom is same as the top.

Any advice is appreciated. I know this may be a complicated issue, so let me know if need to clarify anything.

> **The project is available on GitHub at this link: https://github.com/MagnalityMusic/Bracing**

*I am using a boat model to test the buoyancy, it has 4 gameobjects with the Floater script attached.*

Thank you!

Comment: Which tutorial have you followed? What's the implementation of the GetWaveHeight() method? The github link you've provided results in a 404 for me (private repo?).

Comment: Since I have less than 10 reputation, I had to limit the amount of links I posted haha, sorry about that. I also accidentally included the '.' in the link for the github I have corrected that now. The tutorial I followed is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awd1hRpLSoI&t=249s&ab_channel=Zicore. The link for the buoyancy guide I followed is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL_zHQEju8s&ab_channel=TomWeiland.